# Unity3D activeSelf function always returns true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, I have a script for switching weapons. The script relies on activating and deactivating `gameObjects` that you have picked up. As of now, the `gameObjects` get set inactive in unity, but the function `activeSelf` returns true no matter the actual state. A part of my script is attached. The If-statement works well and I can monitor the state in `Debug.Log`.

This should not be happening, and I have no idea what's the cause.

[image: Unity screenshot]

[image: The block of code manifesting the issue.]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. It is text, and there is a code formatter. Please insert it directly into the question.

Comment: I would say this is a **typo**: `weapon.gameObject` != `gameObject` ...

Answer (score 5):

You control activity of `weapon.gameObject`, but then you check `gameObject`

`gameObject.activeSelf` returns same result every time because you don’t change it actually. You change `weapon.gameObject.selfActive`

Comment: This would be the correct answer